# Given a list of named routes, check for those which user has access to

Tags: laravel-4

If I want to build a basic menu, is there a function I can leverage to test whether a given user has access to a named route?

If not, is there a function to extract the filters from a configured route? I'm seeing the function, but I don't see how to "load" each route first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is just an abstract idea:

```
$route_names = array('ladger.create', 'ladger.update');
$routes = Route::getRoutes();
foreach ($route_names as $routeName) {
    $route = $routes->getByName($routeName);
    $beforeFilters = $route->beforeFilters();
    print_r($beforeFilters);
}
exit;
```

### Output:

```
Array
(
    [auth] => Array
    (
    )

    [permission] => Array
    (
        [0] => create_ladger
    )

)
Array
(
    [auth] => Array
    (
    )

    [permission] => Array
    (
        [0] => edit_ladger
    )

)
```

My Routes (According to example):

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|permission:ladger'), function(){
    Route::post('/ladger/{group}/create', array( 'before' => 'permission:create_ladger', 'uses' => 'LadgerController@create', 'as' => 'ladger.create') );
    Route::post('/ladger/{group}/update', array( 'before' => 'permission:update_ladger', 'uses' => 'LadgerController@update', 'as' => 'ladger.update') );
});
```

This is taken from one of my projects. Hope you'll get the idea that you are looking for. In the `foreach` loop, following line returns an array of `beforeFilters`:

```
$beforeFilters = $route->beforeFilters();
```

So, you may examine this array to determine whether the user has access to this route or not. In my case, I can check the `permission` from the array to determine the user permission like:

```
if( $beforeFilters && count($beforeFilters['permission']) ) {
    // Has permission, check for specific one now...
}
```

This is my `permission` filter which checks for permission before a route gets dispatched (If it helps):

```
// Filter for Permission Checking
Route::filter('permission', function($route, $request, $required_perm){

    // Check if current user has all permissions
    if(currentUser()->is('admin') || (count(currentUser()->permissions) == Permission::count())) return;

    $currentUser = currentUser();
    $user_perms = $currentUser->permissions;

    // Check if user has any permission at all only if the
    // $required_perm is 'any'. With any permission, user
    // can go to the baack end/admin panel.
    if($required_perm == 'any' && count($user_perms)) return;

    // Check if user has any permission with given param,
    // i.e. "create_user" allows access to the user page
    // even if the user doesn't has other user related permissions
    // like, "edit_user" or "delete_user", checks word "_user"
    if($perms = $currentUser->hasAnyWith($required_perm)) return;

    // Check if user has given permission, i.e. "delete_user"
    if($currentUser->hasPermission($required_perm)) return;

    // If comes here then not a valid user
    // with required permission, so get off...
    try {

        return Redirect::back();

    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {

        return Redirect::route('home'); 
    }

});
```